# Reading table details from Database container (.dbc)

Tags: containers, visual-foxpro

I have an application which has about 30 .dbf tables, and these tables are all recorded in a single database container.  A very brief description of each table is held in the Table Comment of each table, and hence in the ‘Property’ field of the relevant record in the dbc.

I would like to offer the user a chance to define a simple report which I would then send to an Excel file (am familiar with the VFP interface to Excel).  To that end I need to display the table name and table comment (and a list of fields from the .dbf file itself).

Is there an easy way to extract the ‘Table comment’ part of the ‘Property’ field?  I believe that I need to parse that field, since the ‘Table comment’ is embedded within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in VFP there are more than one place to get that information. You can use DbGetProp(), ie:

```
open database (_samples+'data\testdata.dbc')
? DbGetProp('Customer', 'TABLE', 'Comment')
```

Also AFields() have that information:

```
use (_Samples+'data\Customer')
afields(laFields)
? laFields(1,16)
```

Comment: Thank you Cetin.  The aFields method (!) is the one I shall use, since I already am using the call to AFIELDS().